# Problemas com o erro Notice: Undefined property: stdClass:

Tags: php, json

Olá sou novo na área de TI e estou desenvolvendo uma API pro tiny  que faça uma consulta de notas fiscais
mais estou com um problema em mostrar esses resultados formatados, criei um `foreach` que tinha como objetivo selecionar somente as informações que preciso que seria o "numero" e o "nome".

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <metacharset = "utf-8">
</head>
<html>
<body>

<?php


    $url = 'https://api.tiny.com.br//api2/notas.fiscais.pesquisa.php';
    $token = '314924f95c4eaf43f0657917defc742205c35317';//token esta invalido por segurança minha.
    $numero= '229199';
    $data = "token=$token&numero=$numero&formato=JSON";

    $retorno = enviarREST($url, $data);
    $content = json_decode($retorno);


    foreach ($content->retorno->notas_fiscais as $nota_fiscal){
        echo $nota_fiscal->numero. " - ".$nota_fiscal->nome."<br/>";
    }
    //var_dump($nota_fiscal);
    function enviarREST($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
    $params = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    ));

    if ($optional_headers !== null) {
        $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
    }

    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
    if (!$fp) {
        throw new Exception("Problema com $url, $php_errormsg");
    }
    $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception("Problema obtendo retorno de $url, $php_errormsg");
    }

    return $response;
}

?>
```

Mas infelizmente me vejo com este erro:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$numero in C:\wamp64\www\APIteste\buscaNF.php on line 21
>   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nome in C:\wamp64\www\APIteste\buscaNF.php on line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro quer dizer que você está tentando acessar um atributo de algo que não é um objeto.

Por exemplo:

```
$xpto->atributo;
```

Se esse $xpto for null ou não for um objeto vai gerar esse erro ao tentar pegar a `propriedade ->atributo.`

Quando temos um retorno do model com relacionamentos, se o relacionamento não existir ou não estiver configurado corretamente, será retornado um null, então teremos o mesmo problema. Por exemplo:

```
$user->role->name;
```

Se esse usuário não tiver um papel (role), será retornado null, então não conseguiríamos acessar a propriedade ->name de null. Nesse caso, para testar poderíamos fazer um:

```
dd($user->role);
```

E ver se não está retornando null.

Faça isso para os relacionamentos que você está retornando para a view.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

você está tentando percorrer com foreach a propriedade notas_fiscais dentro de um objeto da classe stdClass, que é uma classe nativa do PHP utilizada para armazenar dados temporariamente sem termos a necessidade de criar uma classe somente para isso, porém a propriedade notas_fiscais não existe nesse objeto que está sendo percorrido.

Utilize o var_dump e verifique o que a variável $content possui antes de fazer o loop, é possível que os valores estejam armazenados em arrays dentro de obj e não propriedades, em vista que a fonte dos dados é um JSON.

Qualquer dúvida posta o resultado do var_dump()

Comment: Ola,segui seu conselho e dei uma var_dump() no $content e vc tinha razao a classe nao existe la  me retornando isso:C:\wamp64\www\APIteste\teste.php:19:
object(stdClass)[7]
  public 'retorno' => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'status_processamento' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'status' => string 'OK' (length=2)
      public 'pagina' => int 1
      public 'numero_paginas' => int 1
      public 'notas_fiscais' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              ...

Comment: mais quando eu dou um var_dump  no retorno eu tenho o que eu quero: '{"retorno":{"status_processamento":"3","status":"OK","pagina":1,"numero_paginas":1,"notas_fiscais":[{"nota_fiscal":{"id":"606255396","tipo":"S","serie":"1","numero":"229199","numero_ecommerce":null,"data_emissao":"07\/02\/2020","nome":"J ANFLOR ELETRONICOS EIRELI","cliente":{"nome":"J ANFLOR ELETRONICOS EIRELI","tipo_pessoa":"J","cpf_cnpj":"08.218.472\/0001-27","ie":"0570248981","endereco":"AV DORIVAL CANDIDO LUZ DE OLIVEIRA","numero":"2875","complemento":"","bairro":"SAO JERONIMO","cep":"94.040-001"

Comment: mais nao sei o por que nao consigo mostrar isso pela variavel  $content. utilizando o json_decode().